# Linq query to read from a tree recursively

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

My query is supposed to retrieve product category information from the database and populate the viewmodel `ViewModelProductCategory`. The categories will be arranged in a tree structure in a recursive manner, each with a list of products. Also, there is a list of products without any category references, so called orphan products.

When the query reaches `.Select(v => ...`, something goes wrong, and an  "ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null" is thrown:

```
var VMCategories = _context.ProductCategories
                        .Include(e => e.Children).ToList()
                        .OrderBy(s => s.SortOrder)
                        .Where(r => r.ParentId == null) // only need root level categories
                        .Select(v => new ViewModelProductCategory
                        {
                            Id = v.Id,
                            Children = v.Children,
                            ParentId = v.ParentId,
                            Title = v.Title,
                            SortOrder = v.SortOrder,
                            // Get all orphan products (products without category):
                            OrphanProducts = v.ProductInCategory
                                            .Where(o => !_context.ProductsInCategories.Any(pc => o.Id == pc.ProductId))
                                            .Select(orph => new ViewModelProduct
                                            {
                                                Id = orph.Product.Id,
                                                Title = orph.Product.Title,
                                                Price = orph.Product.Price,
                                                Info = orph.Product.Info,
                                                SortOrder = orph.SortOrder
                                            })
                                            .OrderBy(s => s.SortOrder)
                                            .ToList()

                        })
                        .ToList();
```

Below are my entity- and viewmodels:

Entity model for product category:

```
public class ProductCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ParentCategory))]
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    public ProductCategory ParentCategory { get; set; } //nav.prop to parent
    public ICollection<ProductCategory> Children { get; set; } //nav. prop to children

    public List<ProductInCategory> ProductInCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Entity model for product:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public List<ProductInCategory> InCategories { get; set; } // Nav.prop. to occurances in product categories
}
```

Entity model for product in catgegory:

```
public class ProductInCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public int ProductCategoryId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; } // Nav.prop. to product
    public ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; } // Nav.prop. to category
}
```

Viewmodel for product category:

```
public class ViewModelProductCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }

    public string ProductCountInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return Products != null && Products.Any() ? Products.Count().ToString() : "0";
        }
    }

    public ProductCategory ParentCategory { get; set; } // Nav.prop. to parent
    public IEnumerable<ProductCategory> Children { get; set; } // Nav.prop. to children

    public List<ViewModelProduct> Products { get; set; } // Products in this category
    public List<ViewModelProduct> OrphanProducts { get; set; } // Products with no references in ProductInCategory
}
```

Viewmodel for product category with category title (used to display category titles in product view):

```
public class ViewModelCategoryWithTitle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Viewmodel for product:

```
public class ViewModelProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ViewModelCategoryWithTitle> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

**APPENDIX**

I forgot to add the view. First, the model is sent to Index-view, which looks like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyStore.Models.ViewModels.ViewModelProductCategory>
<ul>
    @Html.Partial("_CategoryRecursive", Model)
</ul>
```

Then the Index-view calls this recursive razor-view:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyStore.Models.ViewModels.ViewModelProductCategory>

<ul style="list-style:none;padding-left:0px;">
@if (Model != null)
{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li>
            <ul>
                @Html.Partial("_CategoryRecursive.cshtml", item.Children)
            </ul>
        </li>
    }
}
</ul>
```

Comment: Does every parentId have a child?

Comment: You've got too much going on in that Linq statement to see where the problem is?  As a temporary measure, break it up into parts so you can debug sections more easily.

Comment: @Danieboy No, not every parent have children. Categories can be either root level (maybe have children, but parentId is null), sub level (maybe have children, parentId is some value) or sub-sub-... etc. (maybe have children, parentId is some value).

Comment: Shouldn't your navigational properties in your one-to-many relations be virtual? Shouldn't your Lists be ICollections? After all what does ViewModelProductCategory.OrphanProduct[4] mean? Furthermore, have you checked in your database that every ProductInCategory has a Product? I think the lack of Product is causing the exception.

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse I'm aware that the whole thing about orphan products is a bit weird. What I need in the view is just one list of orphan products, but this query gives me a list for each category. But how can I work that out when I have an IEnumerable of the viewmodel in the view? Regarding lack of products, the view shoud render even without products. I'm new to all this stuff, so I don't know about virtual properties or the difference between List and ICollection.

Answer (score 0):

I think the commenters are right about breaking it up a bit. Obviously I can't test it without your data, but I'd try something like this at first:

```
var cpics = _context.ProductsInCategories;

var vmc = from pc in _context.ProductCategories
          where pc.ParentId == null
          orderby pc.SortOrder
          select new ViewModelProductCategory(pc, cpics);

public class ViewModelProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ViewModelCategoryWithTitle> Categories { get; set; }

    public ViewModelProduct(ProductInCategory pic)
    {
        Id = pic.Product.Id;
        Title = pic.Product.Title;
        Price = pic.Product.Price;
        Info = pic.Product.Info;
        SortOrder = pic.SortOrder;
    }

    public ViewModelProduct() { }
}

public class ViewModelProductCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }

    public string ProductCountInfo =>
        Products != null && Products.Any() ? Products.Count().ToString() : "0";

    public ProductCategory ParentCategory { get; set; } // Nav.prop. to parent
    public IEnumerable<ProductCategory> Children { get; set; } // Nav.prop. to children

    public List<ViewModelProduct> Products { get; set; } // Products in this category
    public List<ViewModelProduct> OrphanProducts { get; set; } // Products with no references in ProductInCategory

    public ViewModelProductCategory(ProductCategory pc, IEnumerable<ProductInCategory> cpics)
    {
        Id = pc.Id;
        Children = pc.Children;
        ParentId = pc.ParentId;
        Title = pc.Title;
        SortOrder = pc.SortOrder;
        OrphanProducts = (from pcpic in pc.ProductInCategory
                          join cpic in cpics
                              on pcpic.Id equals cpic.ProductId
                              into pics
                          from pic in pics.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          where pic == null
                          select new ViewModelProduct(pcpic))
                         .OrderBy(s => s.SortOrder)
                         .ToList();
    }

    public ViewModelProductCategory() { }
}
```

Checking for a null `item.Children`:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyStore.Models.ViewModels.ViewModelProductCategory>

<ul style="list-style:none;padding-left:0px;">
@if (Model != null)
{
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
       @if (item.Children != null)
       {
            <li>
                <ul>
                    @Html.Partial("_CategoryRecursive.cshtml", item.Children)
                </ul>
            </li>
        }
    }
}
</ul>
```

It might have too many @'s - I don't use MVC much.

Comment: This looks promising, however, I get a red squiggly on _context in the ViewModelProductCategory constructor function, telling me that The name '_context' does not exist in the current context. ?

Comment: Try passing the `ProductInCategorys` to the constructor of the `ViewModelProductCategory` - I modified the code.

Comment: That brought me one step further. But now I get an ArgumentNullException in the recursive partial view, which I didn't include in my original question. Please see appendix in my post (which I'l update in 20 seconds).

Comment: Looks like the `Children` that you're trying to pass to your partial view is null.

Comment: But I'm checking for null in the view. If `item.Children` is indeed null, then the recursive traverse should skip to the next parent category? The exception happens on `foreach (var item in Model)`, and if the Model was null, that whole block would not run.

Comment: You're currently checking if `Model` is null and `Model` is a `ViewModelProductCategory`. You're not checking if the `Children` of the `ViewModelProductCategory` is null.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that didn't help. Still getting ArgumentNullException, after first checking `Model`, and then `item.Children` inside the `foreach`, like you suggested.

Comment: Okay. That's as much as I can help then.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the effort.